# 'WorkerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplicationInsights' in isolated Azure function program.cs file

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

I'm getting this dependency error below and I'm not sure why? I manually added "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" package to try and fix the dependency error and have it referenced in my .csproj file. and I have the using statement at the top of my program.cs file, but it still couldn't be found.

I've done a dotnet restore and restarted VS Code a couple of times.

Here is what I see.
[image]

Here is the program.cs and my .csproj

```js
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Configuration;

var sqlConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:SqlServerConnection");
var host = new HostBuilder()
    // .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AddApplicationInsights()
            .AddApplicationInsightsLogger();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString)
        );
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="41.16.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AddApplicationInsights` method is part of the [Azure Functions runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp), and you can use it to enable Application Insights telemetry collection in your Azure Functions.

To use Application Insights with Azure Functions v4, you need to add the Application Insights extensions. As of the latest updates in 2023, there are two NuGet packages you can consider:

1. [`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights): This package is in preview version 1.0.0-preview4. It is compatible with various .NET versions, including .NET 5.0, .NET 6.0, and .NET 7.0, among others, as well as .NET Core and .NET Standard 2.0. The package depends on the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService` (version 2.21.0 or above), `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core` (version 1.11.0 or above), and `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` (version 5.0.0 or above).
2. [`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights/): This package is also in preview version 1.0.0-preview4. It shares similar compatibility with various .NET versions as the first package. This package depends on [`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions/) (version 1.1.0 or above).

To add either of these packages to your Azure Functions project, you can use the `dotnet add package` command in your terminal or CLI, or you can add the package directly in your project file with a `PackageReference`. For example:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0-preview4" />
```

Or:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0-preview4" />
```

---

[Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2524745/vlad) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76378110/workeroptions-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addapplicationinsights-in-is/76395512?noredirect=1#comment135557191_76395512) still
having this issue:

> I use v4 `dotnet-isolated` function, I also added `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights` this package and I have the same builder.
> `AddApplicationInsights().AddApplicationInsightsLogger();`.
> I'm getting the error:
> `error CS1061: 'WorkerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplicationInsights' and no accessible extension method 'AddApplicationInsights' accepting a first argument of type 'WorkerOptions' could be found.`
>
> For me, it was:
>
> 1. To add this namespace in `Program.cs`: using `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;` and
> 2. Use of `preview4` instead of `preview5` here: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0-preview4" />`

While the code compile, it would still not run properly, and freezes:

> You can't even turn off the host (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), only killing the terminal helps. I found out, that there some breaking changes in ["preview5" here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/src/DotNetWorker.ApplicationInsights/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights 1.0.0-preview4
```

AND

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights 1.0.0-preview4
```

for isolated functions to work with app insight